# Matching two arrays index positions for output

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm completely new to learning JavaScript.
So: I have 2 arrays to which values are stored, name and age. The values to these arrays are pushed from html forms.

I'm trying to get output where I'd show a list of underaged and adult members based on the data in arrays.

So far I've figured out how to use filter to figure out to which category the person belongs to based on values on memberAge array, but I can't seem to figure out how could I match this filter to the memberName array where the members name is stored to be able to get output like "Jack , 15" // Name + Age.  Any suggestions how should I proceed with this?

```
var memberName = [];
var memberAge = [];

function namePush() {
  pushName = document.getElementById("txtName").value
  pushAge = document.getElementById("txtAge").value
  memberName.push(pushName);
  memberAge.push(pushAge);
  document.getElementById("pOutput").innerHTML = "Club has "+ memberName.length + " members";
}

function checkMinor(memberAge) {
  return memberAge < 18;
}

function showMinor() {
  document.getElementById("pOutput").innerHTML = memberAge.filter(checkMinor);
}

function checkAdult(age) {
  return age >= 18;
}

function showAdult() {
  document.getElementById("pOutput2").innerHTML = memberAge.filter(checkAdult);
}
```

Comment: Best way to do this will be following OOP concepts and making array of objects with two properties in it, name and age. ```members = [{name: "a", age: 18}, {name: "b", age: 21}]```

Answer (score 0):

Could you consider changing it into a hash map? This would solve the problem and be far more scalable in the long run.

```
const members = {}
function namePush() {
 members[document.getElementById("txtName").value] = document.getElementById("txtAge").value
```

This let's you sort through this object instead and always have names (as keys) match with ages (as values).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use only 1 array of js object

```
var members = [ { name:'paul', age: 24 }
              , { name:'bill', age: 14 } 
              ]
```

full code

```js
const inName = document.getElementById("txtName")
    , inAge  = document.getElementById("txtAge")
    , xOut   = document.getElementById("pOutput")

var members = []


function namePush() {
  members.push( { name:inName.value, age: Number(inAge.value)});

  xOut.textContent = "Club has "+ members.length + " members";
}

function showMinor() {
  xOut.textContent = members.filter(m=>m.age<18).map(m=>m.name).join(' / ')
}
function showAdult() {
  xOut.textContent = members.filter(m=>m.age>=18).map(m=>m.name).join(' / ')
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName" value="" placeholder="name"><br>
<input type="text" id="txtAge" value="" placeholder="age"><br>
<br>
<output id="pOutput"></output><br>
<br>
<button id="Add_Member" onclick="namePush()">Add_Member</button>
<br>
<button id="showMinor" onclick="showMinor()">showMinor</button>
<br>
<button id="showAdult" onclick="showAdult()">showAdult</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample snippet for your question,

use an array to store the name and age

```js
var persons = []; //store the input details into an array

function add(){

  //add person detail as an object into the array
  persons.push( { 
    name: document.getElementById("name").value, 
    age: document.getElementById("age").value
  });
  
  //*******verify the persons age
  
  //count the minors
  var minors = persons.filter(function(aPerson){
    return aPerson.age < 18
  });
  
  var minorsCount = minors.length;
  
  //count the adults
  var adultCount = persons.length - minorsCount;
  
  document.getElementById("minors-count").innerHTML = minorsCount;
  document.getElementById("adults-count").innerHTML = adultCount;
}
```

```html
Name : <input type='text' id='name'> <br>
Age : <input type='text' id='age'> <br>
<br>
<button onClick="add()"> Add </button> <br>
<br>
Minors : <span id="minors-count"></span> <br>
Adults : <span id="adults-count"></span> <br>
```